# Error Running App Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBkIu.png)I am randomly getting an error when running my code. It was working a few hours earlier, but when I restarted my computer I can't run the code. I never changed my AndroidManifest, so I don't see why this error would occur. I tried rebuilding the project and invalidating the caches but it still doesn't work.
AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".StartUpActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LogInActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

There is not error log all its says is "Default activity not found" 
Also the red MainActivity says 
"Unresolved class 'MainActivity' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files."

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: share the crash log please

Comment: attached a screenshot since there isn't a proper error log. Hope it helps

Comment: Did you specify an applicationId in your gradle build file?

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but from the information that you've provided, I can say that I've had a degree of success doing the following:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

It seems that you have a couple of errors there, and a little more information would make it easier to assist you (maybe show your full AndroidManifest.xml so that we can check other aspects of the file for errors).

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Select Edit Configurations from the drop down next to run button.

**2.** Under launch options > Launch select Specified activity.

**3.** Another field "Activity" will appear select your default activity.

**4.** Click OK and sync project with gradle files and it should work.

Comment: It says "Warning: The activity 'StartUpActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml" 
but it is declared in the manifest

Comment: try doing  " sync Project with Gradle files" inside Android Studio->Files->Sync Project, or try cutting it and pasting it again. Another thing is to add the whole package name instead of just the activity name.

Comment: Syncing the project works, I just have to do it every time I start up studios. Thanks!